# How can we create pdf file name with time using itextsharp

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

how can we create pdf file with time in asp.net using itextsharp because i pass short time it create an exception i am using this code for filename

```
 filename = "Invoice" + _InvoiceNumber + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ".pdf";
```

what i need to change in this code i want my pdf file name as

Invoice06-7.00AM

wait for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify DateTime format
"dd-H.mmtt"

where

```
dd - Date
H  - Hours
mm - Minutes
tt - AM or PM
```

Try somthing like:

```
filename = "Invoice" + _InvoiceNumber 
                     + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-H.mmtt");
                     + ".pdf";
```